# how to get the Polysemes of a word in wordnet or any other api?

Tags: nlp

how to get the Polysemes of a word in wordnet or any other api. I am looking for any api. with java any idea is appreciated?

Comment: I think this will be a much better question if you define polysemes, and state what you have done so far to answer your question. This doesn't seem to be about data science at the moment.

Comment: @SeanOwen its always better if you dont comment, if you have no idea on subject.do you know what is polysemes?

Comment: of course I do. You misunderstand my suggestion. It's for the benefit of readers who might help you with a resource on "words with multiple meanings" but don't recognize the word 'polyseme'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several third-party Java APIs for WordNet listed here: http://wordnet.princeton.edu/wordnet/related-projects/#Java

In the past, I've used JWNL the most: http://sourceforge.net/projects/jwordnet/

The documentation for JWNL isn't great, but it should provide the functionality you need.